# 5 red dots. Internet not working or showing up. Computer ports don't work anymore

Tags: updates, settings

Earlier I kept getting a pop up saying I was having system issues.

I decided that if I updated the system, maybe it would fix the issue because I wasn't sure what the issue was.

So I ran the update and it asked me to restart my computer. So I did, but on reboot I have lots of problems. During the loading screen I got 5 red loading dots that appeared on my screen before I was prompted to login. After i logged in I noticed the desktop appearance had reverted back to deafault and I had many problems:

- My side panel was enlarged.
- My top bar was black instead of clear like I set it.
- My system settings are the same as I set them to be but the appearance is not as it should be.
- My internet, both ethernet and WiFi aren't working anymore, none of my computer ports are working.
- My usbs, hdmi, my touch screen(it's a 2 in 1 laptop),
- my multi-touch on my TouchPad.

None of that is working anymore. I've been using my phone to look on the internet for solutions but I can't find anything.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to fix the problem.

I had to access the GRUB boot menu and boot a previous kernel by selecting it from the **Advanced Options for Ubuntu** menu. Under the previous kernel, everything was working normally.

I re-downloaded and reinstalled the new updates again andrestarted the computer. The new updates reinstalled and it worked just fine! Everything was working fine again under the new updates.